# ¿Guardar solo la parte entera de un float o double en Java?

Tags: java

Me gustaría saber si hay algún método para guardar la parte entera de una variable de tipo float en otra variable de tipo Integer. He estado buscando y no he encontrado nada, estoy ahi con la duda. Un saludo!

Comment: Busca por el método `floor`.

Answer (score 6):

Basta con que hagas un casting de la variable  a su  correspondiente tipo de dato en este caso sea un int o un long

Ejemplo

**Float a entero**

```
float real = 14.444f;
int entero = (int)real;
```

**Double a entero**

```
double real = 14.444;
int entero = (int)real;
```

Lo mismo aplica para los long